# Google sheets Script with 2 conditions to move row to new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure a google sheets problem. I have a master sheet (which is a form response sheet) And I need to copy data to indivdual contractors pages (there are 22 or more individual contractors)  Line 22 or next available after line 22) IF Move is selected in F column. I could do this with a query Importrange. The problem is I want this to stay on the sheet it is moved to. So not copied actually moved from the master sheet to the contractor sheet. When the contractors name is selected AND Move is selected in the F column. I do not know how to do that.  But I am guessing since there are so many contractors I will need something on the contractors sheet or? a single script for each contractor? or I am over thinking this.

Master Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PqXc1XDyhg3nGSia4klxsuoKQtmPcBiDBrgJQr5uwyE/edit?usp=sharing

Contractor Page
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k3as6E30cytNfkzHC55clEH5Jik90aIXOrkgsjRXgEs/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID HERE","IN Order!A1:B"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 = 'Grace'")
```

Comment: You must filter column F too for F='Moved', so you must define range as you need, not A1:B but A1:F, and if you don't want get another column, you define the select not with * but directly with 'Select A, B'

Comment: Hello Connie, I have a few questions for you. 1) Do you have one Spreadsheets file per contractor? Or are they all in independent Sheets within a Spreadsheets file? In case it's the former, how are you willing to identify each file?. 2) In the contractor Sheet, which is the data you are trying to import and where? Cheers

Comment: I do have one Spreadsheets file per contractor. they are not conected. There is not a date. What it is a discplanary form. We document everything for admin. but only want certain things to go to the contractors permanent file.  So I would like a drop down menue on column F that says "moved" or transfer or Keep anything that copies permently the information over to the contractors employee file.

Comment: Hey Connie. There is a problem with your current Sheets organisation: From the Form Results Sheet, we can obtain the name of the contractor. However, there is no way to find the "Contractor Page". Do your contractors by any chance have an ID that identifies them? Is there a drive folder in which you have all your contractor page Sheets perhaps? What name do they have if so?

Comment: Each employee is identified by their name. Each employee has an indidual contractor file.   Last Name, First name Contractor file.  All stored in a Folder named Contractor Files.